# Proportion of positive/negative label in Supervised Learning

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, supervised-learning, labels

I'm working on a Supervised Machine Learning problem and I have a question about the proportion of positive/negative label.

I would like to categorize some batch as OK or NOK. But actually my batchs are most often OK.
To give you an idea, at the moment I have approximately 400 batchs OK and 10 NOK.

My questions are :
What will be the impact on the results of this proportion? 
Is it still possible to have conclusive results? If so, with what type of algorithm?